# Listing all paths to leaves in generic (non-binary) list-of-list tree

Tags: python, tree

I have a tree encoded in this way:

```
[A, [B, [G, [H], [I]]], 
    [D, [C], [E], [F]]]
```

This represents the following structure:

```
        A
       / \
      B   D
     /   /|\
    G   C E F
   / \
  H   I
```

Furthermore, the leaves all contain 'end' rather than an actual letter so H, I, C, E, F, are actually all 'end'

Another way to view the list that might be more intuitive.  In this case, indentation represents the tree level

```
[A, 
    [B, 
        [G, 
            [H], 
            [I]
        ]
    ], 
    [D, 
        [C], 
        [E], 
        [F]
    ]
]
```

I want to traverse the tree and list all paths to leaves

```
[A, B, G, H]
[A, B, G, I]
[A, D, C]
[A, D, E]
[A, D, F]
```

I wrote this function that can traverse the tree and correctly identify leaves, but I'm not sure how to build the paths as lists like I have above:

```
def leave_paths(lst, level=0):
    #level is used to keep track how far in the tree we are to
    #perform various functions - removed here for simplicity
    if lst[0] == 'end':
        #This is a leaf!
    for i, l in enumerate(lst[1:]): 
        if type(l) is list:
            leave_paths(l, level + 1)
```

As far as I can tell this works right, but I'm not sure how to keep track of the paths such that they are formatted in the way I described.

Comment: Where are `H` and `I` in the input? I don't understand how the list encodes the tree.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed.  Basically, every time a list starts it's a new level in the tree.  Each list is made of the parent node (not a list), and then all of its children.  Each child is a list because it is a different level of the tree

Comment: Just some comments on your code: Explicit type-checking is usually a code smell in Python. Also don't use the lowercase L as an identifier, it looks too much like other characters and makes your code hard to read / causes ambiguity. Lastly, don't use identifiers that are similar to built-in functions such as the `list` constructor: you might accidentally mistype `lst` and end up with a bug that's hard to track down.

Comment: The function is there to address 'what have you tried' type of things, I'm not married to it :)  E.g. this is the logic I tried, I can trivially change the type check to something else equivalent.

Comment: So what's the problem with just passing the path(s) back as a return value?

Comment: I'm not sure how to accomplish this such that each path is a separate list.  If it's utterly trivial feel free to post an answer with that :)

E.g. it should return a list of lists, where each list is a path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recursion you should identify your base case, and then how to build upon that base case with **simple individual steps** in order to make more complex cases.

**Base case**:
The leaf is what is unique to each path, which seems like a clue that you can start with the leaf when constructing your path. Pass a list containing the leaf back as a return value, this is your base case. In the case with only one node, you'd end up with just a single value in a single list (only one path).

**Recursive case**: You'll need to get the results of your recursion (up to 2 branches according to your example) then prepend the current node to each of the children's result lists (likely more than 2 unless there was no branching below the current node). Return the results after prepending.

**Edit:** Since you asked so nicely for some code, here's basically what you could do:

```
def leave_paths(current):
    # Identify leaves by their length
    if len(current) == 1:
        return current
    # Take all branches, get the paths for the branch, and prepend current
    return [[current[0]] + path for branch in current[1:] for path in leave_paths(branch)]
```

This should net you a single list of "path" lists. Note how we're re-flattening at each recursive step by iterating through the `branch`es, then also iterating through the result `path`s of each `branch`, and putting the prepended-to results into a single result `list` comprehension as our return value.

Comment: As much as I appreciate the answer and I would love for this to be useful to me, it isn't.  I understand what I have to do in theory.  It's just unintuitive to me to figure out how to pass the path parts around through he recursion in the appropriate way.  I have already tried to figure this out before posting.  Also, the tree can have arbitrary depth.

I guess to me your answer suggests that the implementation is trivial, in which case, why not post it?  In the case that implementation isn't trivial, then obviously this type of answer isn't helpful since the hard part is implementation :)

Comment: I will add some sample code you can use in your program. I wanted to avoid giving you a complete implementation since, although it's a pain in the ass, translating an informal specification into code is a really important part of the development process. I don't see my original answer as useless, since putting the task into words as an informal specification is an even more important part. If you had already done this you should have posted it in your question.

Comment: Sure, depends on the goal I guess.  By the time I post on stackoverflow it's like several hours after exhausting everything I can accomplish in a reasonable time frame.  I understand the goal and can probably figure it out on my own eventually, but probably far more slowly than someone more used to recursive logic, which I don't often deal with.  But I wrote the function that generates the original list, so I can certainly traverse this tree along all paths and keep track of them - but only in a way that basically replicates the structure that already exists.

Comment: I understand, of course you could be having trouble with the implementation step, I just didn't want to jump the gun in case you felt capable of doing it yourself. Please see the edit to the post for a possible implementation. I haven't tested it but perhaps you get the idea enough to try it out with your code. Are you familiar with how list comprehensions work?

Comment: Yes, I'm not new to python, I just don't deal with recursive logic often - probably would not have thought of that solution for a while, but now I know it forever :).  Actually your answer didn't immediately work `can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`, since the 'A','B','C', etc that get returned by the comprehension are strings, but changing the `[current[0]]` to `current[0]` fixes it.  Thanks

Comment: I was thinking you wanted a `list` result so I would have gone the other way around (make sure `path` is always a `list`, starting with the base case- you might have to wrap `current` in a list constructor depending on how you've defined your base case). Anyway cheers and happy coding :)

Comment: By the way if you're looking to get comfortable with developing these kind of recursive walk-up/walk-down functions, I'd highly recommend practicing some mathematical proofs by induction. It's one of those things where it really resembles the programming pattern, so practicing one naturally lends to skills in the other.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter for me which way, and that one seemed simpler and gives ['ABCD'] rather than ['A','B,'C','D'].  Might be worth for future people to post that version though.  I guess most people would want that.  I'll leave that decision to you, for me this answer works :)  For me python is more of an applied thing than educational - typically recursion is not feasible for my use cases because of memory usage so I almost always opt for iterative solutions even if they are cloogy.  In this case though it's just keeping track of a path so it's useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115769/discussion-between-machine-yearning-and-chp).

Answer (score 0):

Here are more applied copy-paste answer for two use cases, based on (and mostly a copy of) machine yearning's answer:

Create paths that are one long string, e.g. ['ABCDE']

```
def leave_paths(current):
    # Identify leaves by their length
    if len(current) == 1:
        return current

    # Take all branches, get the paths for the branch, and prepend 
    return [current[0] + path for branch in current[1:] for path in leave_paths(branch)]
```

And if you want the paths as a list, e.g. ['A','B','C','D','E']

```
def leave_paths(current):
    # Identify leaves by their length
    if len(current) == 1:
        return [current]

    # Take all branches, get the paths for the branch, and prepend 
    return [[current[0]] + path for branch in current[1:] for path in leave_paths(branch)]
```